# How to set Emmet preferences in Brackets

Tags: preferences, brackets, emmet

I tried to create a preferences.json file and enter its path in Emmets "Preferences"-dialogue as prescribed, but either nothing happens or emmet stops working. I tried out numerous possible locations for the file, in AppData, ProgramFiles and several subfolders (Win10). I tried all possible ways of writing down the filepath as well as the preference-file itself, e.g.:

```
{
"format.noIndentTags": "body"
}

{
"format.noIndentTags": body
}
```

Nothing helped. You'd assume it's not two evenings worth of research to simply set preferences, this is an (undocumented) shame.